# Does analytic at a point imply differentiable at that point?

Tags: complex-analysis, analyticity

A function $f:A \subset \Bbb C \to \Bbb C$ is said to be analytic if it is locally given by a convergent power series i.e. every $z_o \in A$ has a neighbourhood contained in $A$ such that there exists a power series centered at $z_o$
which converges to $f(z)$ for all $z$ in that neighbourhood.

Does that mean that this power series should also converge to $f(z_o)$ at $z_o$?

Comment: Analytic implies differentiable, even for real-valued functions.  The really impressive fact is that, for complex-valued functions, differentiable implies analytic.

Comment: @Slade is it possible $f$ is analytic on a *deleted* neighbourhood of $z_0$ but not analytic at $z_0$? sounds like this might've been what OP is asking. i believe this is impossible for both real and complex.

Comment: @JohnSmithKyon $f(x)=e^{-1/x^2}$ is smooth and analytic at a deleted neighborhood of every point, but is not analytic.  But you are correct that the two definitions are equivalent over $\mathbb{C}$.  This is basically Riemann's Theorem on removable singularities, which is a pretty quick consequence of differentiable implies analytic.

Comment: @Slade thanks. did you mean $g=e^{-\frac{1}{x^2}}1_{\mathbb R \ \setminus 0}, g: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$? or really $h=e^{-\frac{1}{x^2}}, h: \mathbb R \ \setminus 0 \to \mathbb R$?

Comment: @Slade wait for the complex case 1 - ok i guess $f$ defined $A \ z_0$ is really not by itself analytic on $z_0$ but it is by its extension since $z_0$ is apparently a removable singularity? 2 - wait if $f$ is really defined on the whole $A$ but analytic on $A \ z_0$, can we say $f$ itself is analytic at $z_0$ too?

Comment: @Slade or wait perhaps just answer here: [Analytic on deleted neighbourhood implies analytic on whole?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4275879/analytic-on-deleted-neighbourhood-implies-analytic-on-whole)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$z_0$ is in the neighborhood centered at $z_0$ (here I mean that the neighborhood does contain $z_0$), so the power series does converge to $f(z_0)$ at $z_0$ by definition. $f$ is hence differentiable at $z_0$ as any power series is differentiable.

Comment: ShakesBeer, is it possible $f$ is analytic on a *deleted* neighbourhood of $z_0$ but not analytic at $z_0$? sounds like this might've been what OP is asking. i believe this is impossible for both real and complex.